# 'int' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python-3.x

Estou com um problema em relação ao seguinte código:

```
for x0 in range(len(matriz)):  # Abaixo foi aplicada a fórmula de transformações lineares para linhas e colunas.
    xn = transformação[0][0] * x0 + transformação[0][1] * x0 + y0 + transformação[0][2] % (len(matriz))
    for y0 in range(len(matriz[0])):
        yn = transformação[1][0] * x0 + transformação[1][1] * y0 + transformação[1][2] % (len(matriz[0]))
        matrizt[xn][yn] = matriz[x0][y0]
        y0 += 1
    y0 = 0
    x0 += 1
```

O erro é o seguinte:

> 'int' object is not subscriptable

Mais especificamente, o erro é em relação à linha:

```
xn = transformação[0][0] * x0 + transformação[0][1] * x0 + y0 + transformação[0][2] % (len(matriz))
```

Comment: Isso significa que `transformação[0]` está retornando um inteiro. Então `transformação` não é uma matriz com duas dimensões, mas apenas um vetor/matriz de uma dimensão. Sem detalhes da criação dessa variável, não posso fazer mais nada além do que já disse

Comment: Obrigado, Jefferson. Tentarei aplicar.